# Regex to match word and trailing whitespace pairs

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I have a text:

```
"    Alice, Bob    Charlie  "
```

and I would like to get pairs of word (if any) and the whitespace after it. That is:

```
[("", "    "), ("Alice,", " "), ("Bob", "    "), ("Charlie", "  ")]`
```

In Python, I tried:

```
re.findall(r"(\S*)(\s*)", "    Alice, Bob    Charlie  ")
```

which almost works - it just adds an empty pair `("", "")` at the end. How to get rid of it? Except for .pop()? Also, I don't really understand why it is there at all - after it matches Charlie's whitespace it should finish, no?

Edit: to clarify - I want the first pair, i.e. no word with some whitespace. The last one - no word, no whitespace - is the one I want to get rid of. Without .pop(), possibly...

Comment: `*` means match _zero or more_, so it matches an empty string. Just because you have it twice doesn't mean it they won't both match the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would do that

```
re.findall('(\S+|^)(\s*)', s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall(r"(\S+)(\s*)", "    Alice, Bob    Charlie  ")
```

with a `+` sign after the `\S` returns what you probably want:

```
[('Alice,', ' '), ('Bob', '    '), ('Charlie', '  ')]
```

otherwise `\S*\s*` can possibly match empty string at the end: zero-or-more and zero-or-more can equal to zero-length too.

Other possibility (apart from `.pop()`) would be:

```
[a for a in re.findall(r"(\S*)(\s*)", "    Alice, Bob    Charlie  ") if a != ('','')]
```

or:

```
re.findall(r"(\S*)(\s*)", "    Alice, Bob    Charlie  ")[:-1]
```

both of which return exactly what you need (included the whitespace at the beginning):

```
[('', '    '), ('Alice,', ' '), ('Bob', '    '), ('Charlie', '  ')]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. He wants the empty whitespace at the beginning too.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `\s*` to `\s+` to require at least 1 character of whitespace:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\S*)(\s+)", "    Alice, Bob    Charlie  ")
[('', '    '), ('Alice,', ' '), ('Bob', '    '), ('Charlie', '  ')]
```

Comment: What if he wants to match a name with no trailing whitespace?

Comment: If the text was "   Alice, Bob   Charlie" - Charlie wouldn't match.

Comment: Then change the second group to `(\s+|$)`: one or more whitespace characters **or** the end of the string.  But the original regex worked for the example given in the question.